# urxvt ~/.Xresources not reading/loading?

Tags: rxvt

Yesterday I created a file called `.Xresources`, and I can't seem to get it to load into `urxvt`. I have tried pasting in stuff, and restarted the terminal, logged in and logged out, restarted my computer several times.

But I still have this white GUI. What do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: You might want to try and put `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` in a file like `~/.xinitrc` if that file gets loaded.

Answer (score 8):

There is no specific `.Xresources` to examine, so only general advice is possible.

The `.Xresources` file is usually loaded by `xrdb` (a ***prop*** for desktop settings).  You can test this file by simply loading directly with `xrdb`, e.g.,

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

or just

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

if you do not care for the desktop-designer's choices.

If there is some *conflicting* resource definition, the *more specific* one is used.  For instance, if you had

```
urxvt*background: blue
```

and some desktop feature loads

```
urxvt.background: gray
```

you would get a gray background because the `.` is more specific than `*`.

You can see what `xrdb` did:

```
xrdb -query
```

If there is a resource needed by the application which is not set in the root window using `xrdb`, that resource is loaded according to the usual X resource rules (e.g., the system app-defaults files as well as your own `.Xdefaults` file).

If you are *not* running in a desktop environment that automatically runs `xrdb`, much of the advice regarding `xrdb` is probably not useful.

Further:

- [X resources](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources) (Arch)
- [.Xdefaults vs .Xresources](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=71742) (Arch)

Comment: The problem is, whatever I write used xrdb to try to load it and restarted terminal, no results. Nothing happens.

Comment: That should be `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` instead of `xrdb merge ~/.Xresources`.